# How to test multiple properties of an object

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm getting a JSON structure from an API and need to check, whether the successfull response has two specific attributes with specific values.

Key problems:

1. I cannot compare the whole object, as there are some properties, which may vary with each request
2. I cannot write two tests (for each attribute), because it can be considered as successful response only when both attributes matches the right values.

Example successful response:

```
{
    'success': true,
    'user_ip': '212.20.30.40',
    'id': '7629428643'
}
```

Dirty solution would be

```
<?php
public function testAddAccount() {
    $response = $this->api->addAccount( '7629428643' );

    $this->assertTrue(
        $response->success === TRUE &&
        $response->id === '7629428643'
    );
}
```

But I think there must be better and cleaner solution, is there?

Comment: That looks pretty clean to me.

Comment: That solution can tell you only that the test fails, but cannot tell you what exactly goes wrong, that's mostly why I consider that as "dirty".

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `assertEquals()` for each property you want to verify. While you typically want to test only one thing in each test case, sometimes multiple assertions are required in order to test that "one thing". For this reason, multiple assertions are okay.

You may also want to assert that the properties exist on the `$response` object to avoid notices. See the following for an example:

```
public function testAddAccount() {
    // Attempt to create an account.
    $response = $this->api->addAccount('7629428643');

    // Verify that the expected properties are present in the response.
    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('success', $response);
    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('id', $response);

    // Verify the values of the properties.
    $this->assertEquals(true, $response->success);
    $this->assertEquals('7629428643', $response->id);
}
```

Comment: Still, it has kinda a defect in the way, that in case of fail, it shows you only fail of the first problematic assert, once you fix it, it shows you another.

Comment: This is true, but it's best to focus on one failure at a time anyway. It is not uncommon that fixing the first failure will also resolve remaining failures within a test case.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the difference between the response and the right answer ignoring any excessive values. If there's no difference, everything's fine; if there is, you'll get the complete information.

```
//some examples
$responseValues = array('success' => true, 'user_ip' => '212.20.30.40', 'id' => '7629428643'); //success
$errorResponseValues = array('success' => false, 'user_ip' => '212.20.30.40', 'id' => '7629428643'); //failure
$errorResponseValues2 = array('success' => false, 'user_ip' => '212.20.30.40', 'id' => '123'); //failure

$expectedValues = array('success' => true, 'id' => '7629428643'); //what is success

function whatIsWrong($reality, $expectation)
{
    return array_uintersect_assoc($reality, $expectation, function($a, $b){return (int)($a == $b);}); //This is slightly dirty, I think the final implementation is up to you
}

var_dump(whatIsWrong($responseValues, $expectedValues)); //array()
var_dump(whatIsWrong($errorResponseValues, $expectedValues)); //array('success' => false)
var_dump(whatIsWrong($errorResponseValues2, $expectedValues)); //array('success' => false, id => 123)
```

Then you may use assertEqual(whatIsWrong(...), array()), which should output the difference on failure, or handle it in pretty much any preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

If `assertTrue()` stores the boolean of a succesfull response this is the way how I would handle it. Keep in mind that this is a matter of **taste**.

```
private $lastResponse;
// $id given elsewhere
public function testAddAccount($id) {
   $this->lastResponse = $this->addAccount($id);
}

private function addAccount($id) {
   return $this->api->addAccount($id);
}

private function isLastResponseValid($response){
   return $this->lastResponse->success === TRUE 
   && $this->lastResponse->id === '7629428643';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple assertions in a single test method for cases like this. Also, use the more specific assertions such as `assertEquals` whenever possible as these will provide better failure messages.

```
public function testAddAccount() {
    $response = $this->api->addAccount( '7629428643' );

    self::assertTrue($response->success);
    self::assertEquals('7629428643', $response->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some answer, you should use `assertEquals()` method. The second part is that you might use a few assertions. So if the phpunit detects failure on the first assertion, the whole test fails.

Why not to use `assertTrue()`? Because it is not clear if you, for example, use `if ($object) ...` in one place of code and `assertTrue($object);` in other one.

Also, be sure your routine executes correctly. So if you get the exception while trying to get the response - test will fail. While exceptions should be checked also as a test cases. That is, you should try posting an incorrect request and assert exception is thrown. That's how good test looks like - it should check all possible situations, hehe =)

So, this is the code you should got:

```
public function testAddAccount() {
    $response = $this->api->addAccount('7629428643');

    $this->assertEquals($response->success, true);
    $this->assertEquals($response->id, '7629428643');

    $this->setExpectedException('MyException');

    $response = $this->api->addAccount('wrong_account');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I can think of (although this *is* a matter of taste) would be to add the two boolean expressions and assert the result is two:

```
$r1=$response->success === TRUE;
$r2=$response->id === '7629428643';
$this->assertEquals(2, $r1+$r2, "Expecting both values to match; got ($r1) and ($r2)");
```

Of course, you can extend this setup to any number of tests with arrays and `array_sum()==count()`, and more loveable messages.